# JavasScript Pseudo Protocol Function is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have this JavaScript function:

```
function sgIframeSrc(pageID = 0) {
    return 'https://app.mydomain.com/more/stuff';
}
```

And I'm trying to run this function using the JavaScript Pseudo Protocol from an iframe `src=""` attribute by doing the following:

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src="javascript:sgIframeSrc()"></iframe>
```

My function is written out in a JS file in the `<head></head>` and the iframe is further down in the DOM, so the function is available to be ran, and does work if I run it from the console or elsewhere in code; however I get the following console error from the pseudo protocol code:

```
ReferenceError: sgIframeSrc is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here, or is the pseudo protocol even inteded to work this way? Is there a better way to run the function inline so my iframe source is set dynamically inline with the rest of the DOM?

Comment: A browser which doesn't support default parameters?

Comment: Default function parameters? I've tested in Chrome and Firefox, same results in both browsers. Hang on, I'll try to remove the function parameter and see if it works.

Comment: Same result with the function parameter removed. `sgIframeSrc is not defined`

Comment: If I swap my function out for an alert or console log it works as expected. I'm at a loss as to why it can't find my function though.

Comment: And no other errors in the console?

Comment: No other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `top.sgIframeSrc()`

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src="javascript:top.sgIframeSrc()"></iframe>
```